# Primary Key using timestamp+ guuid

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing, primary-key

I have large data , will it differ in indexing performace if I have epoc+guid vs guid+epoc as primary key since epoc are sorted.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, a primary key is a logic concept, rather than a physical concept, but it's usually implemented using an index (which is a physical concept). On InnoDB, that index will affect the order in which data is stored. This means that when writing to the table, it will have to re-order the data in the order of the primary key if the primary key value isn't neatly appended to the end.

Therefore, using epoc+guid should be *much* faster than guid+epoc, as long as the epoc reflects the time of writing the data to disk. If the epoc is some other value - business transaction date, date of birth, whatever - the difference is harder to predict.

As GUIDs are guaranteed unique, I'm not sure why you would ever want to have guid+epoc.

Answer (score 1):

`INSERT`:  guid+epoc will be somewhat slower.  It will become much slower when the table is bigger than can fit in the buffer_pool.

`SELECT`:  If you tend to access only "recent" data, then epoc+guid could be significantly faster.  ("locality of reference")

If you use "Type 1" UUID and shuffle the bits, then you get both features (uniqueness and time-ordered) in a single field.  (Smaller is better.)  More:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/uuid Also, MySQL 8 has equivalent functions.

To discuss further, please provide the type of data, size of data, and type of inserts/selects/updates/deletes.